# Get elements of associated array based on values

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array ( 'jan' => 2, 'feb' => 1, 'mar' => 2, 'apr' => 1 )
```

..and I want to return:

```
Array ('jan', 'mar')
```

As in, find the 2 elements with the highest count and put them in an array. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`max()`](http://php.net/max) to get the maximum value, and [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) to get an array containing the keys that had that value.

```
$max = array_keys($array, max($array));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this one works when you need to get fixed number of top values.

```
$array = array( 'jan' => 2 'feb' => 1 'mar' => 2 'apr' => 1 );
arsort($array);
$i = 0;
$max = 2;
$newArray = Array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  if ($i < $max)
  {
    $newArray[] = $key;
  }
  $i++;
}
```